# Searching through a directory to find a certain Project number

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, file, directory

I Have many job files that each have a properties folder I wanna be able to search through the files and find the job that has a certain number assigned to it. These Numbers are contained inside a text file. How can i go about doing this?

Edit:
File Structure CURRENT JOBS FOLDER => MULTIPLE JOBS brakes down [Into This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmQgP.jpg)
inside the properties folder they contain all the information about the job. Including the Job Number i want to search for.

I am Currently stuck on searching multiple files for a text file containing the job number that i need.

Comment: Can you share the folder structure and sample file contents? Also, what do you have so far, and which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Sooner or later, sooner here, a programmer discovers that he needs a database because the file system no longer cuts it.

Comment: I know haha but the owners dont want that they want this...So here i am database would be so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good example [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which finds every *.txt file, starting in C:\ and going through each directory recursively, and then reading each line of text from each of those files looking for the text "Microsoft". I think it can be adapted to solve your problem?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                        where line.Contains("Microsoft")
                        select new
                        {
                            File = file,
                            Line = line
                        };

            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} files found.", files.Count().ToString());
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill give it a try